# Python creating specific list from another list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, reverse, enumerate

Learning python I encountered the following problem. I already have some list with integer numbers (for example `initial_list`). Then I'm trying to create list (for example `result`) with following numbers pattern:

```
result[len(result) - 1] = 1
result[i] = result[i + 1] * initial_list[i]
```

Example:

```
initial_list = [2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2]
result = [192, 96, 48, 24, 12, 4, 2, 1]
```

Here is my first implementation:

```
import numpy as np
initial_list = [2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2]
result = [1]
for number in reversed(initial_list):
    result.append(result[-1] * number)
result = np.array(result[::-1])
```

Here is my second implementation:

```
import numpy as np
initial_list = [2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2]
result = np.ones(len(initial_list) + 1)
for i, number in enumerate(reversed(initial_list)):
    result[len(result) - i - 2] = result[len(result) - i - 1] * number
```

I guess second one is much better because it does not contain append method and initialize list with concrete size. Also `result = np.ones(len(initial_list) + 1)` consists with float point number which is not correct. I wonder whether there is a simpler version of the implementation of this algorithm.

After that algorithm I'm creating `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
ordered_dict = OrderedDict(zip(other_list, result))
```

Maybe I can reverse `result` list during creating `OrderedDict` for `O(1)` "on fly" like `reversed` works in for looping, so that I can simplify algorithm above.

Comment: what is the algorithm supposed to do?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It should create list from initial list with patter that mentioned above:`result[len(result) - 1] = 1, result[i] = result[i + 1] * initial_list[i]`

Comment: I think a list comprehension would be a good idea, but I'm having trouble figuring out your algorithm. For instance, `result[len(result) - 1] = 1` only makes sense if `result` has some data in it. What does `result` look like at the beginning?

Comment: FWIW `result.reverse()` will do an inplace reverse

Comment: @abaiter Sorry, I should mention that this pattern is not a program instructions,  I just need result list with last element equal 1 and all other from recursive formula

Comment: @Demyanov By the way, in the future, questions like these should probably be asked on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) if the code already works beforehand (after reading the [help center guidelines](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), of course).

Comment: @Quill Maybe I misunderstood? I read the *"I wonder whether there is a simpler version of the implementation of this algorithm."* part specifically and thought that it would make more sense there since it seems to be a problem of code optimization. In the [on-topic section](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), it seems to say that *"Best practices and design pattern usage"* are on-topic *"for feedback on a specific working piece of code from your project"*. Clearly, you would know better than me what is off-topic, but I just don't understand why you believe so.

Comment: You'd be correct, it seems, thank for you reading the on-topic section, and help center guidelines. OP, feel free to take this to Code Review if you please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) is an option, you can do it with [`cumprod`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumprod.html):

```
import numpy as np

initial_list = [2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2]

>> np.append(np.cumprod(initial_list[:: -1])[:: -1], [1])
array([192,  96,  48,  24,  12,   4,   2,   1])
```

Comment: numpy is definitely an option, they are using it ;)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham :-) Right you are. Thanks!

Comment: @AmiTavory In a single line, that is what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) and [`operator.mul`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.mul)

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>> from operator import mul
>>> a = [2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2]
>>> list(accumulate(reversed(a + [1]), mul))[::-1]
[192, 96, 48, 24, 12, 4, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Nice combination of itertools + operator.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just do

```
result = [0] * len(initial_list)
result[-1] = 1
for i in xrange(len(result) - 2, -1, -1):
  result[i] = result[i + 1] * initial_list[i]
```